# How to dynamically remove the last Char in a String in C#

Tags: c#, string, console, char, immutability

I am creating a console application upon which the user can type in a train station and find the train stations. For this, I am appending the `Console.ReadKey().Key` to a String each time.

When the user types an incorrect letter, I want the `ConsoleKey.Backspace` to remove the last Char in the String.

```
    private void SetDepartingFrom()
    {
        String searchQuery = "";
        ConsoleKey keyIn;

        while ((keyIn = readKey(searchQuery)) != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            if (keyIn == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                searchQuery.TrimEnd(searchQuery[searchQuery.Length - 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                searchQuery += keyIn.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private ConsoleKey readKey(String searchQuery)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Stations Found:");

        if (searchQuery != "")
            App.Stations.FindAll(x => x.GetName().ToUpper().Contains(searchQuery.ToUpper())).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetName()));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Stations found...");

        Console.Write("Search: " + searchQuery);

        return Console.ReadKey().Key;
    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
if (keyIn == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    searchQuery.TrimEnd(searchQuery[searchQuery.Length - 1]);

if (keyIn == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    searchQuery.Remove(searchQuery.Length -1);

if (keyIn == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    searchQuery[searchQuery.Length -1] = "";
```

None have worked. I understand Strings are immutable in C#, however, is this possible or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `searchQuery = searchQuery.SubString(0, searchQuery.Length - 1);`

Comment: Use a StringBuilder()

Comment: @LegacyCode thanks! If you drop an answer for this, I'll be sure to mark it. This worked.

Comment: @rene really a StringBuilder?

Comment: @LegacyCode yes, you have a problem with that?

Comment: @rene - yes ... It's like flying to the Bahamas to take a shower and go back to work in Canada. He only wants to remove the last char. Why a StringBuilder? It's costy and does not make sense in the context.

Comment: @LegacyCode there is more in that code that could benefit from a stringbuilder, depends on what cost you want to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is immutable so you have to use the value returned by TrimEnd.

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.TrimEnd(searchQuery[searchQuery.Length - 1]);
```

In this case I think [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) method would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, strings are immutable. All of the instance methods on the `string` type (at least those related to "modifying" it) return a new string. This means that calling something like the following returns a new string which is immediately discarded:

```
// value is discarded
searchQuery.Substring(0, searchQuery.Length - 1);
```

The solution is to *reassign* the variable with the new value. For example:

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.Substring(0, searchQuery.Length - 1);
```

[SharpLab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQiAM7EGYAEA3uvqfogkSWTQG4CGY+AzgKaMDGAFgIoStgAnvgC8pAEQBZYQGVgYAJZQA5uIDc1GqTade/IaJbsw3PgMEA6GRABGcJJgAUmADRHdZoRYAyrFcC58AFp8JABKDTQtMnsATkcdEz1zCPwAejT8AAdFKGBmfClZeSVxfE18AF90SqA=)

If you are using C# 8 you can make use of the *range operator* via the [`Index`/`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) classes. This provides a bit cleaner version:

```
// backspace one character
searchQuery = searchQuery[..^1];
```

[SharpLab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQiAM7EGYAEA3uvqfogkSWTQG4CGY+AzgKaMDGAFgIoStgAnvgC8+AEQBBAEIBhcQG5qNUm069+QkWrDc+AwQG0AdMYB6SALpK0KsnCQBOABQ69mwQEobNAL7pfIA===)

I will also note that `TrimEnd` is most likely *not* what you want. It will trim more than one character at a time which isn't what a *single* press of the Backspace key would do. For example consider the following:

```
var str =  "Abcdeee";
var result = str.TrimEnd('e');
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "Abcd"
```

[SharpLab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQiAM7EGYAEA3uvqfogkSWTQG4CGY+AzsEwLykBEAggEYBjACYBTMVwDc1GqQZMwI5hAA2wfJ1ZgAdABUwASwC2AUShCAFAHIRlgJRS0MsnCQBOcwqWr7+APS/8AAcDKGBmfF5BIS58aXwAX3R4oA===)

Answer (score 1):

Any method you use to manipulate the string will return the new string so you need to capture that.

`string newString = searchQuery.Substring(0, searchQuery.Length -1);`

Answer (score 1):

It will return a new string, so you need to assign it to a string like this.

```
string newStr = earchQuery.Remove(searchQuery.Length -1);
```

Or to same string you can do like this.

```
earchQuery= earchQuery.Remove(searchQuery.Length -1);
```

You can also use `TrimEnd` and `SubString` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code example which removes the last character from a string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                        
        string founder = "Hell World from Big_Data_Analyst!";  
        string founderMinus1 = founder.Remove(founder.Length - 1, 1);  
        Console.WriteLine(founderMinus1);           
            
        }
    }
}
```

The input string in the code is

```
Hell World from Big_Data_Analyst!
```

The output string is

```
Hell World from Big_Data_Analyst
```

As you see the last character which is `!` is being removed in the output